# Firefox 4 Alternative to Status Bar Messages

Tags: javascript, statusbar, firefox4

Firefox 4 has done away with the status bar. I used `window.status` to display some informational messages to users of my web app. Is there any alternative comparable feature built into FF4 that I can use instead? If showing these messages requires an add-on then you can bet that 90% of my users won't see them.

Comment: IIRC: The status bar isn't **gone**, it just doesn't show unless there's something to show.

Comment: No that is different. There is nothing that changes when you set `window.status` to a string. What you have now is an "Add-on Bar" or a "hover URL shower" neither of which is easily set from JS

Comment: To clarify, this isn't a typical use case. I agree 100% that obfuscating the status bar text to hide or lie about the destination of the links is evil and wrong. My use case is to display some diagnostic information to users of my tool as they browse their sites. I tell them to turn on the status bar if they want that information. This is much easier than trying to some how build some display window that will not alter the current page to contain the status information.

Answer (score 2):

The status message hijack has been a bad practice that's fading away. I think the default behavior for javascript in this browser is to not let hijack it.

Solution: find another way. A tooltip, create your own status bar, do it with the `title` attribute, etc. Don't rely on something like the status bar.

Comment: Changing the page title might be a solution. However any solution that involves changes to the content of the page and not the chrome is non-optimal for my specific use case. Just because there are bad apples doesn't mean that you should toss the entire bushel.

Answer (score 2):

Whether it's "bad practice" to use or rely on status messages is highly debatable. If you are designing a work-oriented desktop app, then how they render on phones is moot. Good practices for one device may not be good for others. If you cater to the lowest common device features, then you cannot leverage the advantages of more powerful devices. I'd say the utility of status messages depends on the usage and type of application.

Answer (score 0):

Not everyone HAS the status bar turned on or even a title bar.  (Consider phones and tablets that do away with these things just to increase a little screen real estate.)  Also with more and more touchscreen devices entering the fray, mouseover is also going to become less useful.

Do consider alternatives.  Also remember, hiding information from the user until they click or hover the right spot in a deadly sin of GUI design.